# How to silence background music leaving only vocals no matter quality?

Tags: music, background

I am using pitch analyzer app to write down notes of singers voice in a song but background music (instruments) makes it difficult. I am sure there is some Eq, filters setting that can make only vocal frequencies loud making rest as silence as possible. Sound quality is not important, but what matters is only pitch of a singers voice.

Comment: In general, the frequencies used by musical instruments overlap the frequencies present in the human voice. Some sounds, like a kick drum, might have hardly any overlap, but the main instruments that are making it hard to hear the vocals are probably masking because the frequencies overlap. You might be able to high pass at around 300 to 500 Hz and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I am beginner in sound editing, can you please explain how to do this. I use Adobe Audition and Cool Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Todd is right about the frequency overlap in his first OP reply comment, meaning simple EQing may not get you the results you require.

However, something else to note is that the main vocals are commonly centered, spacially. So extracting this 'centre channel' will remove the unwanted side channels from the stereo file. The bass is also commonly centred, so will remain, but lower frequencies will be easier to control on the mono output signal that is returned from this process.

[Adobe CCE](https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/using/stereo-imagery-effects.html)
[Explanation from MusicHack](https://musichack.wordpress.com/gw-tutorials/center-channel-extractionisolation/)

**You should Search this site (SSD) for 'Remove vocals'(very similar process) and 'Extract vocals' to get some other ideas.** This subject is like a holy grail for audio professionals. It has widespread implications, so it is a common question on this site.